# Product of $n$ primes greater than $m$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

What are some good bounds for the logarithm of the product of the first $n$ primes greater than $m$?

I also want to address a confusion I have:

The logarithm of the product of the first $n$ primes is roughly $n\log n$ so the product in question should be roughly
$$(n+\pi(m))\log(n+\pi(m))-\pi(m)\log\pi(m),$$
but this is smaller than $n\log m$, which is absurd.

Comment: Where did $(n + \pi(m))\log(n+\pi(m))$ come from?

Comment: $n+\pi(m)$ is the index of the $n$th prime greater than $m$

Comment: ""The logarithm of the product of the first $n$ primes is roughly $n log(n)$ "" ; Did you check this ? Do you consider that this approximation is good enough to use it ? Do you search a formula for any values for $n$ and $m$, or for certain range ( example $n<100$ and $m > 10^{15}$ ?

Comment: The behavior will be different when $m$ is large compared to $n$ as opposed to when $n$ is large compared to $n$. Which situation did you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

We have the [well known formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) for the sum of logarithm of primes up to $x$
$$
\sum_{p \leq x}\log p = \Theta(x),
$$
from which it follows that
$$
\sum_{m \leq p \leq x} \log p = O(x-m).
$$

The $n$'th prime is $\Theta(n \log n)$ so
$$
\sum_{i \leq n}\log p_i \approx \sum_{p \leq n\log n} \log p = \Theta(n \log n).
$$
The first prime after $m$ is $\pi(m)$'th prime, so the last prime is the $\pi(m) + n$'th prime, therefore would be of size $\Theta\left((\pi(m) + n)\log(\pi(m) + n)\right)$.

the result that you are looking for is
$$
\sum_{m \leq p \leq (\pi(m) + n)\log(\pi(m) + n)} \log p = O((\pi(m) + n)\log(\pi(m) + n)-m).
$$

Comment: Isn't this still much smaller than $m\log n$? Take $m=n^2$ for instance

Answer (score 1):

If k is small compared to n, then the k-th prime after m is about m + k log m or m * (1 + k/m log m). The logarithm is about log m + (k/m log m). The sum for the first k primes after m would be about k log m + (k^2 / 2m * log m), and the value about m^k * m^(k^2 / 2m).

A comment asked about k = 100, $m = 10^{15}$, here the product is $m^{1500} * (10^{15})^{5000 / 10^{15}}$ or $m^{1500} * (1 + 1.727 / 10^{10})$ apart from mistakes I may have made.

This is an estimate, not bounds. For $k=100$ and $n > 100000$ it should be reasonably accurate.